# Elements go out from a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a trouble with the following code because **li** elements go out from a div with class **center**

```
<!doctype html><html><head>     
  <style>
  #selectable {line-height:3em}
  #selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
  #selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white}
  #selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
       #selectable li { margin: 3px; padding: 0.4em; font-size: 1.4em; display:inline}
  .center { margin: 0 auto; width: 50%; background: silver; height:500px}  
  </style>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

 <script>       
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var arr=['33033', '04444', '00555', '333333', '4444444', '555555', '666666', '77777',  '666666', '77777'];
        $(document).ready(function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                $("#selectable").append("<li class='ui-widget-content'>" +arr[i] + "</li>");
            }
        });
    });

    $( function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable({
      stop: function() {
        var result = $( "#select-result" ).empty();
        $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
          var index = $( "#selectable li" ).index( this );
          result.append( " #" + ( index + 1 ) );
        });
      }
    });
  } );

  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="center">

<ol id="selectable"></ol>

</div> 
</body>
```

How can I fix it?

Note that you need jquery-ui.css on you local disk to replay the effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the selector styling (for `#selectable li`) is changed like below, believe it would yield the expected result:

```
#selectable li {
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Snippet to work with:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var arr = ['33033', '04444', '00555', '333333', '4444444', '555555', '666666', '77777', '666666', '77777'];

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $("#selectable").append("<li class='ui-widget-content'>" + arr[i] + "</li>");
  }
});

$(function() {
  $("#selectable").selectable({
    stop: function() {
      var result = $("#select-result").empty();
      $(".ui-selected", this).each(function() {
        var index = $("#selectable li").index(this);
        result.append(" #" + (index + 1));
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#selectable {
  line-height: 3em
}
#selectable .ui-selecting {
  background: #FECA40;
}
#selectable .ui-selected {
  background: #F39814;
  color: white
}
#selectable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 60%;
}
#selectable li {
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  display: inline-block;
}
.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  background: silver;
  height: 500px
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="center">

  <ol id="selectable"></ol>

</div>
```

*Suggestions:*

- Avoid the usage of `$(document).ready` inside `$(document).ready`
- Instead of using hard-coded value (of 10 which is the number of elements in the array) in the loop, we could use array length property (`arr.length`):

> ```
> for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
>     $("#selectable").append("<li class='ui-widget-content'>" + arr[i] + "</li>");
> }
> ```